# Determine if PHP files is Running as Part of a `phar` archive

Tags: php, phar

Is there a way to determine, at runtime, if a PHP file is running as part of a `phar` archive?

i.e., a native implementation might look something like this

```
function isRunningAsPhar()
{
    $first_include = get_included_files()[0];
    return strpos($first_include, '.phar') !== false;
}
```

However, this might not work if the user has renamed the phar to have a different file extension, or symlinked the phar to remove the file extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the function `Phar::running();` That gives you a path for the executed phar archive. If the path is set then its an archive.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/phar.running.php

Example from manual:

```
<?php
$a = Phar::running(); // $a is "phar:///path/to/my.phar"
$b = Phar::running(false); // $b is "/path/to/my.phar"
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice little function that will return a true or false based on whether a file runs in PHAR Archive or not

```
function isPhar() {
  return Phar::running() !== '';
}
```

Link: http://lesichkov.co.uk/article/20170928111351676090/handy-php-functions-when-working-with-phar-archives

How to use example:

```
if(isPhar()){
    echo 'Script is running from PHAR';
} else {
    echo 'Script is running otside PHAR';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate it directly like this:

```
if (Phar::running()){
    echo "Script is running from a phar";
}
```

No need to create new unneeded functions.